# Permanently Configure two X Servers

Tags: rhel, x11, xorg

I'm trying to permanently configure a second X server to start at runtime on RHEL 7. I am aware that I can start a second x server using `startx -- :1 vt 2`, but I'd much rather integrate it to the xorg.conf than running it in rc.local or creating a custom service.

How can I permanently configure a second X server to start at boot while taking advantage of xorg.conf?